# flyway migrations with postgresql and postgis extension

Tags: spring, postgresql, postgis, flyway

I have 2 schemas in my db:

```
CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;

CREATE SCHEMA my_second_schema;
```

So i created an extension

```
 CREATE EXTENSION postgis
  VERSION "2.1.4";
```

and used it well with both schemas.

But flyway 3.0 works with only first schema, on my_second_schema throwing an error:

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 803: CREATE TABLE places (
        id bigint DEFAULT nextval('places_sequence'::regclass) NOT NULL,
        geo_location geometry,
        created_at timestamp without time zone,
        updated_at timestamp without time zone,
        version bigint,
        state boolean
    )
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:752)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 803: CREATE TABLE places (
        id bigint DEFAULT nextval('places_sequence'::regclass) NOT NULL,
        geo_location geometry,
        created_at timestamp without time zone,
        updated_at timestamp without time zone,
        version bigint,
        state boolean
    )
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:91)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:287)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$5.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:285)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:285)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.access$800(DbMigrate.java:46)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:207)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:156)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:156)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:864)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:811)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1171)
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:811)
        at co.brandly.configuration.FlywayMigration.init(FlywayMigration.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1682)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1621)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
      Позиция: 276
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:235)
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:89)
        ... 62 more
```

So why there is 'ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist'?

My spring application context:

```
 <bean id="flyway" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="schemas" value="my_second_schema, my_schema"/>
            <property name="validateOnMigrate" value="false"/>
            <property name="outOfOrder" value="true"/>
            <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="$flyway{"/>
            <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
            <property name="placeholders">
                <map>
                    <entry key="schema" value="${flyway.placeholders.schema}"/>
                    <entry key="schema_analytics" value="${flyway.placeholders.schema_analytics}"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in users privileges or something.

```
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;
```

This helps

Comment: There has to be a better answer.  That won't work in AWS RDS, for example, where someone operating as rdsadmin needs to enable the extension.  Once the extension is enabled, you can create geometry columns.

Answer (score 0):

Hey maybe your problem is that you didn't add all the extension in your schema :

```
-- Enable PostGIS (includes raster) 
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
-- Enable Topology
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology; 
-- fuzzy matching needed for Tiger 
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
-- Enable US Tiger Geocoder
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

As of flyway 3.1 there is baseline target, executing that which will treat your database as an existing database with postgis functionality already imported to your schema when creating the database with postigs_template.